# Drawing bitmap buttons android

Tags: android, button, bitmap

So Im making a start screen for a game. At the moment all it has is the background image and the button image. Ill post my code below and then explain the issues...

```
public class TitleView extends View {

    private Bitmap titleGraphic;
    private Bitmap scaledTitleGraphic;

    private Bitmap playButtonUp;
    private Bitmap scaledPlayButton;

    private Bitmap playButtonDown;
    private Bitmap scaledPlayButtonDown;

    private Boolean playButtonPressed = false;
    private int screenW;//storing width...
    private int screenH;//storing height...


    public TitleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        titleGraphic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.title_graphic);
        //scaledTitleGraphic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(titleGraphic,screenH,screenH,true);
        playButtonUp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play_button_up);
        scaledPlayButton = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(playButtonUp, 400, 125, true);
        playButtonDown = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play_button_down);
        scaledPlayButtonDown = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(playButtonDown, 400, 125,true);
    }

    @Override //gets the width and height...
    public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenW = w;
        screenH = h;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawBitmap(titleGraphic, (screenW - titleGraphic.getWidth())/2, 0, null);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(scaledPlayButton, (screenW - playButtonUp.getWidth())/2, buttonPosition , null);
        scaledTitleGraphic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(titleGraphic,screenW,screenH,true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledTitleGraphic, 0, 0, null);

        if(playButtonPressed){
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaledPlayButtonDown, (screenW - scaledPlayButtonDown.getWidth())/2, (int) (screenH*0.7) , null);
        }else{
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaledPlayButton, (screenW - scaledPlayButton.getWidth())/2, (int) (screenH*0.7) , null);
        }

    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        int X = (int)event.getX();
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        switch (eventaction ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(((X > ((screenW-playButtonUp.getWidth())/2)) && (X < (((screenW-playButtonUp.getWidth())/2) +
                        playButtonUp.getWidth()))) && ((Y > (int)(screenH*0.7)) && (Y < (int)(screenH*0.7) +
                        playButtonUp.getHeight()))){
                    playButtonPressed = true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                playButtonPressed = false;
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do this? First of all when I put the background it didnt fit so i used the createscaledbitmap method. Is this popularly used or should i make perfect resolution images some how?? I feel a little weird defining two bitmaps one for the original image and then the other for the scaled image.

Secondly I faced a similar problem with the button. Initially when I put my button on it was huge covered most of my screen so i thought i should make it smaller and i went in photo shop and made it 100x40 but that was still too huge? So I also had to scale the bitmap. Im just confused I mean... I know that its good practice to put images of all resolutions to target devices with different resolutions but i feel like my approach isnt correct because in this case i should just put one HUGE image and just scale all the time?

What Im trying to say is...Im following this from a book but its a little old the book a few years old is there a better approach I should know about? I mean for example I want to use an on click listener etc but instead in this approach im using onTouchEvent?